# Prolog finding target number in a list by applying operations (+,-,/,*)

Tags: prolog

The task is to find if there exists at least one combination of numbers from given list and operators to obtain target number. No usemodule allowed
numbers([3,4,1,2], 7) → true. (cause 4 + 3 = 7)
numbers([1,7,7,3], 24) → true. (cause (7 - 3) * (7 - 1) = 24)

Tried member if target is already in the list. But lost further

Comment: you didn't specify the allowed operators

Answer (score 3):

Building upon https://professor-fish.blogspot.com/2009/11/countdown-with-prolog.html

```
solve_countdown(Ns, SumWanted, TsUniq) :-
    findall(T, (
        any_comb(Ns, Sub),
        num_combs(Sub, T),
        SumWanted is T
    ), Ts),
    sort(Ts, TsUniq).

any_comb(_, []).
any_comb([H|T], [E|Comb]) :-
    select(E, [H|T], Lst0),
    any_comb(Lst0, Comb).

num_combs([N], N).
num_combs(As, T) :-
    split_list_in_2(As, As1, As2),
    num_combs(As1, T1),
    num_combs(As2, T2),
    % Break symmetry, since 5+2 is same as 2+5
    (   T1 @=< T2,
        (   T = T1 + T2
        ;   T1 > 1, T = T1 * T2
        )
    ;   T = T1 - T2
    ;   T = T1 / T2
    ),
    R is T,
    integer(R),
    R @> 0.

split_list_in_2([H1, H2|T], [H1|Start], Remainder) :-
    split_list_in_2_(T, H2, Start, Remainder).
    
split_list_in_2_(L, H2, [], [H2|L]).
split_list_in_2_([H|T], H2, [H2|Start], Remainder) :-
    split_list_in_2_(T, H, Start, Remainder).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(solve_countdown([1,7,7,3], 24, Ts)).
% 10,996 inferences, 0.002 CPU in 0.002 seconds (99% CPU, 5236642 Lips)
Ts = [3*(1+7), (7-1)*(7-3)].
```

`select/3` code [is here](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#select/3).

Answer (score 2):

Squeezing the lemon. I get a slightly faster version.
The logic replicates this paper:
[https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/countdown.pdf](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/countdown.pdf)
But adds forward checking:

```
% solve(+Integer, -Term, +Integer, +List, -List)
solve(1, N, N, P, Q) :- !, select(N, P, Q).
solve(K, G, N, P, Q) :-
   J is K-1,
   between(1, J, I),
   L is K-I,
   solve2(I, E, A, P, H),
   forward(E, A, F, B, G, N),
   solve(L, F, B, H, Q).

forward(E, A, F, B, E+F, N) :- N > A, B is N-A, A =< B.
forward(E, A, F, B, E-F, N) :- A > N, B is A-N.
forward(E, A, F, B, E*F, N) :- N mod A =:= 0, B is N div A, A =< B, A =\= 1.
forward(E, A, F, B, E/F, N) :- A mod N =:= 0, B is A div N, B =\= 1.

% solve2(+Integer, -Term, -Integer, +List, -List)
solve2(1, N, N, P, Q) :- !, select(N, P, Q).
solve2(K, G, N, P, Q) :-
   J is K-1,
   between(1, J, I),
   L is K-I,
   solve2(I, E, A, P, H),
   solve2(L, F, B, H, Q),
   combine(E, A, F, B, G, N).

combine(E, A, F, B, E+F, N) :- A =< B, N is A+B.
combine(E, A, F, B, E-F, N) :- A > B, N is A-B.
combine(E, A, F, B, E*F, N) :- A =< B, A =\= 1, N is A*B.
combine(E, A, F, B, E/F, N) :- B =\= 1, A mod B =:= 0, N is A div B.
```

Example run with SWI-Prolog 9.1.4:

```
% time((between(1,6,N), solve(N, E, 999, [1,3,5,10,25,50], _), fail; true)).
% % 2,618,953 inferences, 0.234 CPU in 0.242 seconds (97% CPU, 11174199 Lips)
% true.
```